# How do I create a new version of my app in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, version

I am working with Xcode 11 and Swift and trying to develop an app.  I have a prototype finished with some functionality, but now I would like to start working on building in some of the more complex features, which will deactivate some of the prototype features (things like going from actions that occur when a button is pressed to occurring on a time instead).  I need to maintain the functionality of my prototype as well, however.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious about Xcode, because surely there's a way to save what I have as Version 1.0 and continue my work as Version 1.1, but I'm not finding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build on the answer if @duncan and @noah when using version control you can manually change the version and build number in target and general there is a section you can change both the build and version number.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to do this is with source control. You'd set up a repository for your source, and make your new version a separate branch.

Comment: Apple's documentation on version contorl: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UsingSourceCodeControl.html

Comment: Note that Xcode's integrated source control features are not very good. You're probably better off using a 3rd party application like SourceTree, Tower, or Github desktop.